# Login-AzureRmAccount Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: powershell, azure, tls1.2, azure-powershell

I am trying to connect to Azure using Powershell. When I try the command Login-AzureRmAccount, I get a pop-up to enter my credentials. But, immediately after that I get an error:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount : Service returned error. Check InnerException for more details: The underlying connection was
closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
At line:1 char:1
+ Login-AzureRmAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureRMAccountCommand
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

**Update**
The below inner exception is what I see:

> 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException:
>   Service returned error. Check InnerException for more details --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could
>   not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
>   Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
>   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpWebRequestWrapper.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpHelper.d__0
>   `.MoveNext()    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.RunAsyncTask[T](Task`1
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.UserTokenProvider.DoAcquireToken(AdalConfiguration
>   config, PromptBehavior promptBehavior, String userId, SecureString
>   password)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.UserTokenProvider.SafeAquireToken(AdalConfiguration
>   config, ShowDialog showDialog, String userId, SecureString password,
>   Exception& ex)
>       ErrorCode: service_returned_error
>       StatusCode: 501'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Login-AzureRmAccount $Error[0].Exception.InnerException

Comment: Have you checked the InnerException? So long as that was the last error you saw, you can run: `$Error[0].Exception.InnerException` to see the inner exception.

Comment: I have added the exception details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this will bypass your problem but not actually solve it.

**DISCLAIMER:** This is not secure, and should *only* be done if you are certain that the certificate error you are getting is a false positive, or you truly don't care! This method leaves you open to establishing connections to malicious and/or compromised sites. This is the PowerShell equivalent to going to a web page in Internet Explorer, getting a certificate error, and clicking the Continue Anyway link.

If you try to manually login, and get a certificate error, but are ok with continuing past it then you can disable certificate checking in PowerShell so that it behaves similarly. Running this line before you try to login to Azure will disable certificate checking for the current session. You will have to run this each time you want to login to Azure, so long as there is a certificate error.

```
 [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

A better solution would probably be to resolve the SSL/TLS issue that you are seeing, but that is most likely something better suited for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or something.