# Powershell Azure : Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: azure, powershell, ssl, tls1.2, azure-powershell

I am trying to connect to the Azure from Powershell and getting following errors .

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Login-AzureRmAccount
Login-AzureRmAccount : Service returned error. Check InnerException for more details: The request was aborted: Could
not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At line:1 char:1
+ Login-AzureRmAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzureRmAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand



Add-AzureAccount : Service returned error. Check InnerException for more details: The request was aborted: Could not
create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AzureAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureAccount], AadAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureAccount
```

[This did not help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420500/login-azurermaccount-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secu#44423568)

Powershell version:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.590
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.590
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

And windows version is : 
Window 10.

Comment: what os\powershell version\azure modules version? try updating to latest modules?

Comment: Try to run `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"` in your powershell, then `Login-AzureRmAccount`, will it work?

Comment: @JoyWang cool , it is working . 
Thank you !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could run `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"` in your powershell, then `Login-AzureRmAccount`.