# Connect-AzAccount: The SSL connection could not be established ... remote certificate is invalid

Tags: azure, powershell

```
Connect-AzAccount: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Looking for a command line option to temporarily disable validation for testing or environment variable to set within Windows to point to different cert bundle.

Answer (score 1):

[Login-AzureRmAccount Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420500/login-azurermaccount-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secu)

Looks like someone had a similar issue which they worked around by running the following in PowerShell:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

Any luck there?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately that didn't let us bypass the check in this case. We are doing to switch to using the AZ command line interface since that allows us to define the certs: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/use_cli_effectively.md#work-behind-a-proxy